# Laravel хранение изображений в папке wp-content

Tags: laravel

Переписал сайт с WP на Laravel, картинки остались в папке /wp-content
На сервере картинки не открываются, выдает ошибку 404, я понимаю что Laravel не видит изображения в папке /wp-content, тк он их открывает из папки /public
Ссылки на изображения у меня хранятся в БД, так что переносить изображения сложно. Нужно настроить хранилище из папки /wp-content

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно настроить filesystems.php и возможно нужно сделать символическую ссылку. По документации пока не получилось разобраться.

код filesystems.php сейчас выглядит так, стандартно:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что все пути к изображениям хранятся в абсолютных путях

Comment: https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/image.png